# Making Device to Send Data to Smartphones: 100m range, 1kb/s bandwidth, low power

Tags: wireless, signal, android, protocol, iphone

What I want to make: A device that immediately sends a notification if the device incurs a moment of high acceleration. The notification needs to denote the acceleration. There is no guarantee that there will be a The device needs to be very small, about the size of a penny, and not much thicker. The device should last for a year using a standard watch battery (about 80% of the time, the device will not be moving at all, the device wouldn't send more than 100 times a day).

Bonus qualities:
 - This notification would be sent to a smartphone for convenience and possible future visualization purposes. 
 - The notification would be visible from up to 100m away from the device (this could be achieved via wireless signal).

What I'm asking for: Advice on through what medium this notification could be sent (Bluetooth, Zigbee, Wifi), and if it can't be sent to a smartphone, what it could be sent to to achieve the goals of the device (most notably, immediately notifying that the device was accelerated, and how much it was accelerated).

Comment: What *are* your power requirements? You're missing a number there.

Comment: My power requirements is that the device should last a year on a single 3V watch battery.

Comment: How often will you be transmitting during this year of life? And what other power usage, besides the communication, will be occurring?

Comment: CR2032 is only 240mAH. What is your power budget for peak current when the device is active? And what is your nominal quiescent current consumption when the device is inactive?

Comment: There will be a small microprocessor, but the computation will be minimal. Nearly all the power would be through communication.

Would it be unrealistic to think that it would be transmitting continually?

Comment: I'm not an EE guy, so I'll just tell you what my idea is.

It's essentially a tiny accelerometer, gyroscope, and microprocessor with an antenna. The parts I've gathered are smaller than a penny when laid out on one (I've had a friend pick out the parts).

The sole purpose of the device to transmit, from up to 100m away, moments of high acceleration (50+ G's) (linear and rotational). About 80% of the time, the object will not be moving at all, and when the object is moving, it shouldn't peak over 50G's more than 100 times a day.

Comment: Read the CR2032 Battery datasheet (e.g. Energizer or other brand), look at the pulse discharge characteristics graphs, and see if a watch battery like this is a good fit for your application. There are other common types of watch batteries, you will need to check those as well -- CR2032 is just one of the most commonly used. Success or failure depends on whether you can find a reasonable balance between operating power and battery size.

Comment: If the receiver must be a smartphone, what else is there besides WiFi, GSM, and Bluetooth? Were you thinking of making a receiver to interface with the smartphone e.g. using USB-OTG? Does the 100m range have to be omnidirectional, or can you reliably point a pair of directional antennas at each end of the link?

Comment: Hi Mark, I've updated the question and gave more details. I see that sending the notification to a smartphone directly may be impossible given the constraints I mentioned earlier, so I relaxed and prioritized the goals and requirements in the edited question summary.

Comment: ***To the person that voted to close:*** the OP is not looking for a specific product or place to purchase. He is trying to figure out which type of RF device to use based on his power requirements.  Note that I didn't give any specific recommendations in my answer either.  This question and answer(s) will not become "rarely useful to others" or "quickly obsolete" as the criteria for closing states.

Comment: @tcrosley  This question is not *off-topic→shopping*, but it is *too broad*.  The O.P. should give it a good thought himself first.  Crowdsourcing a design must be the last resort, not the first.

Comment: @NickAlexeev It was marked as being off-topic as a shopping question -- click on the close(1) link and you'll see that too broad is not checked (at least for now).  And I disagree with that also.

Comment: @NickAlexeev The question is applicable to many devices that have similar requirements. Why is that a bad thing?

Comment: @JoeBenassi  You haven't given this issue of yours enough thought before posting the question.  That's not a good thing.

Comment: @NickAlexeev what makes you think that? I did give it thought. I looked up Bluetooth but the resources I found stated it had too short a range for the power available. I considered Wifi, but there is no guarentee that Wifi would be available. I considered giving the device a network connection, but that wouldn't be economical. I looked up Zigbee, but I couldn't find examples of that working with smartphones. I'm not an engineer, and I know that engineers would know of many more options that I couldn't find and understand by purely browsing forums.

Answer (score 3):

You indicated Bluetooth doesn't satisfy your requirements, and I agree.  But that's classic Bluetooth.  Are you familiar with BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy, part of the Bluetooth 4.0 spec)?  The maximum range is anywhere from 50m to 450m, depending on the module used.  (That last figure is not a typo, here is the [BLE121LR](https://www.bluegiga.com/en-US/products/bluetooth-4.0-modules/ble121lr-bluetooth--smart-long/) -- LR for long-range.  And it still runs off a coin cell battery.)

Apple added support for BLE starting with the iPhone 4S.  BLE is also supported by Android OS (such as used on the Galaxy S series) version 4.3 or later.

I have seen BLE chips with maximum transmit power ranging from 12 mA to 39 mA.  I'm currently using one that is 18 mA, so let's use that.

No, it will certainly not be transmitting continuously.  The trick is to get it to transmit for a brief a time as possible.

If one assumes a connection is made and data is sent in 50 ms with a 10% duty cycle, and that is done 100 times per day, then the power required is 18 mA * .05s * 0.1 * 100 = 9 mAs / day (where mAs is milliampSeconds).

Spreading that over a year, gives 9 * 365 / 3600 = 0.9 mAh per year.  Even if I got the communication time off by *five times*, that would still be  around 4.5 mAh per year.

Assuming the microcontroller is only active when sending data, it should use no more than what the BLE device uses, so that is 0.9 to 4.5 mAh / year.

The problem, I believe will be the accelerometer.

You said 20% of the time, the object will be moving, and there will be less than 100 peak events per day.  I am going to assume that there is some sort of trigger in the accelerometer that allows it to remain in low power until the 50 G event is seen, and only then wake-up the microcontroller.

Assuming the low-power (but active) mode of the accelerometer takes 25 µA, then 0.025 mA * 24 * 365 = 219 mAh. You haven't provided the part number of the accelerometer so I don't know if the 25 µA figure is reasonable.  I took it out of a spec sheet for a Freescale accelerometer I have used.  I am not including the extra power needed when it is connecting to the microcontroller, but that will be very small and can be ignored.

219 + 4.5 + 4.5 = 228 mAh, less than 240 mAh, but not much.

Comment: I am not familiar with BLE. This is great information! Thanks! I'll follow up within a week to let you know if this fits my needs.

Comment: @joe if you want something with much less power consumption I would suggest nrf51822 from Nordic Semiconductor. Not as long range but already has examples for what you want